# how to read only one line in a text file which has particular word using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading a **.txt** file, I want to read only 1 line with particular word. I'm using **Qt Creator**.

How can I achieve this?

This is my code so far:

```
 QFile file("/home/a1.txt");
 if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
     QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");
 }
 QTextStream in(&file);
 QString text = in.readAll();
 ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
 file.close();
```

Comment: Read lines until you find the word and write his line?

Comment: i tried QString text = in.readLine() but its only reading first line of the text.

Comment: You do not have any choice) You cannot read one specify line from files, only line by line.

Comment: the word i am interested is on line 3, how can i get it?

Comment: @sasopk assuming the text file does not have fixed length lines that allow you to calculate the offset of the 3rd line and then seek directly to it before reading, you will have to call `in.readLine()` 3 times and discard the first 2 strings and then parse the 3rd string as needed. `in.readLine(); in.readLine(); QString text = in.readLine(); // use text as needed...`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search all lines for a specific word you can do this

```
QFile file("/home/a1.txt");
if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");
}
QTextStream in(&file);
QString text;
while (!in.atEnd()) {
    text = in.readLine();
    if (text.contains(/*Search her for the word you want.*/))
       break;
}
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
file.close();
```

So you loop through all lines. And in every line you check if the word exist. If yes you can stop searching and leave the loop.

I hope this helps!